# How to skip time in NSDate?

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

I want to get difference between dates skipping time means if one date is 13 Jan 2012 - 11 pm and other date is 14 Jan 2012 - 12 am,then difference should be 1 day not 0 day.I mean I want difference between date only, 14 Jan 2012 - 13 Jan 2012, skipping time. I know I can use NSDate api to calculate difference but the problem is it consider time also.So I thought while calculating difference I will skip time but I do not know how to skip time because if I use NSDateFormatter it will return string not date.Please help me what I can do?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you need to do is get the `NSDateComponents` of each date first. Once you do that you can compare the 'day' component to get you difference.

```
NSCalendar *cal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
[cal setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
NSDate *date1 = ....;
NSDate *date2 = ....;
NSDateComponents *comps1 = [cal components:NSDayCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit fromDate:date1];
NSDateComponents *comps2 = [cal components:NSDayCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit fromDate:date2];

date1 = [cal dateFromComponents:comps1];
date2 = [cal dateFromComponents:comps2];

NSDateComponents *diffComps = [cal components:NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:date1 toDate:date2 options:0];

NSLog(@"Days diff = %d", diffComps.day);
```

The date API can be kind of weird to wrap your head around, but once you do it is quite powerful.

Comment: What about if there is difference in year or month?It was just an example.

Comment: Sorry for asking this question  but I really do not understand,what is "initWithCalendarIdentifier"?What if Calendar in ipad gets changed?

Comment: It's a named calendar style. `NSGregorianCalendar` is the standard calendar used in the western world, but the api allows you to pick other calendars as needed. Its not the kind of thing that changes between devices.

Comment: I got your point but my question is if in code I use  NSGregorianCalendar and calculate difference and if user changes calendar style from ipad then my api will not return correct value,right?

Comment: So you want to use the system calendar? In that case you can do ' NSCalendar *cal = [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleCalendar];' to get a calendar.

Comment: I tried your this option but it is giving 0.For cal it is not allocating I am getting 0X0.

Comment: I would just use the NSGregorianCalendar...I'm not sure if its even possible to change.

Comment: yes with NSGregorianCalendar it is working fine but I am not sure will this work for other calendar can you please give me some permanent solution?

Comment: @Nuzhat Zari: Try using `[NSCalendar currentCalendar]` to get the user's calendar.

Comment: Using [NSCalendar currentCalendar] also I am getting nil.